# How do I turn a string into a function?

Tags: javascript, string, function, eval

How do I turn a string into a function?
I've seen "How to turn a String into a javascript function call?" and a few others, but they didn't fit.
I cannot use `eval` in any way.
I cannot access the actual string. Consider it a predefined string that throws an error when you try to access the value.
SOLUTION QUESTION: Is there a way to NOT use `eval` and yet make a `parseFunction` function, like `parseInt` and `parseFloat` but with functions?

Comment: `I cannot access the actual string` What on earth does that mean?

Comment: Why can't you use `eval`? The normal reasons are avoiding it apply to any form of converting strings into program code.

Comment: @Quentin I forgot to say that I'm coding on a very strict website area. If I get an error, I can't avoid it. If I code `undefined()`, an **unavoidable** error will come up. @SLaks I am playing around with `window.localStorage`. I do NOT know what will come up. @benzonico I haven't tried anything. I don't know what to do. I'm only a beginner.

Comment: What does "very strict website area" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function constructor accepts a string which defines the function intself, so you can do something like this:

```
var f = new Function(string);
```

To call it:

```
new Function('alert("x");')();
```

And you will see an alert which displays an **x**

Passing parameters is defined as this:

```
new Function(arg1, arg2, argN, functionBody)
```

So you can pass a string for alert like this:

```
new Function('arg', 'alert(arg);')('hello')
```

Comment: Except ... some restrictions on the website (see comments on question) are not letting me do this. Is there another way?

Comment: IN this case my advice is this - create another question and post what do you want to achieve and what do you have. I haven't ever used my method here anywhere in my experience and used eval() just a few times I was lazy writing a parser for math equations so I believe your situation doesn't need neither of those.

Comment: @raumaankidwai: What error do you get? If you're getting a CSP error, that means that the website has specifically asked the browser to make it impossible for you to do this.

Comment: @SLaks The website doesn't show the KIND of the error, just the error itself. But sometimes, it will say "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function" or "ReferenceError: rect is not a function`. rect is a function, a built-in function. Here is the link: https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/new