# How do i turn a python string that contains a function so that i can run it?

Tags: python

How do i turn a python string that contains a function so that i can run it?

i found ::
[How do I turn a string into a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19772640/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-a-function)

but i need python not javascript..

i tried running the following in a flask app and didnt work::

```
# Your string containing the function definition with parameters
function_string = "def greet(name):\n    print('Hello, ' + name + '!')"

# Execute the string as Python code
exec(function_string)

# Now you can call the function and pass a variable
name = "Alice"
greet(name)  # This will print: Hello, Alice!
```

that works when i run it on a regular python env by running python3 test.py.

why does this not work on my flask app?

this is the function on my flask app ::

```
    def extract_all_delimiters(self, processed_files_meta_data,set_delimiter_algorithm_fn:str):
        print(f'extract_all_delimiters()')
        delimiters = []
        exec(set_delimiter_algorithm_fn    )
        # set_delimiter_algorithm
        function_string = "def greet(name):\n    print('Hello, ' + name + '!')"

        # Execute the string as Python code
        exec(function_string)

        # Now you can call the function and pass a variable
        name = "Alice"
        greet(name)  # This will print: Hello, Alice!
```

this is the error i see on the console::

```
docwise-backend-web-1     | extract_all_delimiters()
docwise-backend-web-1     | 192.168.65.1 - - [15/Oct/2023 17:22:27] "POST /api/conversation/create_conversation HTTP/1.1" 500 -
docwise-backend-web-1     | Traceback (most recent call last):
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2548, in __call__
docwise-backend-web-1     |     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
docwise-backend-web-1     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
docwise-backend-web-1     |     response = self.handle_exception(e)
docwise-backend-web-1     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
docwise-backend-web-1     |     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
docwise-backend-web-1     |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
docwise-backend-web-1     |     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
docwise-backend-web-1     |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
docwise-backend-web-1     |     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
docwise-backend-web-1     |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
docwise-backend-web-1     |     return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
docwise-backend-web-1     |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
docwise-backend-web-1     |     rv = self.dispatch_request()
docwise-backend-web-1     |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
docwise-backend-web-1     |     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
docwise-backend-web-1     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/app/routes/conversation.py", line 11, in create_conversation_route
docwise-backend-web-1     |     return create_conversation_controller()
docwise-backend-web-1     |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/app/controllers/conversation/create_conversation_controller.py", line 160, in create_conversation_controller
docwise-backend-web-1     |     files_chuncks:List[object] = chunck_text(delimiter_algorithm,files,user_id)
docwise-backend-web-1     |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/app/controllers/conversation/create_conversation_controller.py", line 111, in chunck_text
docwise-backend-web-1     |     extracted_delimiters = delimiter_chuncker.extract_all_delimiters(processed_files_meta_data,delimiter_algorithm['algorithm'])
docwise-backend-web-1     |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
docwise-backend-web-1     |   File "/app/util/text_chunckers/delimiter.py", line 102, in extract_all_delimiters
docwise-backend-web-1     |     greet(name)  # This will print: Hello, Alice!
docwise-backend-web-1     | NameError: name 'greet' is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exec() and variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535284/exec-and-variable-scope)

Comment: Executing on the server untrusted code submitted by a user via a Web application is really really dangerous from a security standpoint unless you’re very careful to put it in its own walled off sandbox. There’s probably a much safer way to achieve your goal than by blindly trusting user-supplied code. Untrusted Python code running on a server can do all kinds of bad things.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? These print calls will not output anything in a webpage if that's what you hope for.

Answer (score 2):

`exec` have two optional parameters, `globals` and `locals`. `globals` refers to the global dictionary and locals refers to the local dictionary.

The referred [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).

In your case:

```
exec(function_string, globals())
```

As for the reason why the first script works and not the flask one, is that for the first script: `exec` adds the function to the global dictionary, whereas when executed inside a function, it is added to the local dictionary of the function.

Alternatively, if you don't want to include the function to the global dictionary:

```
locals()['greet'](name)
```